# SGE Grid Engine error "qsub: Unknown option"

Tags: gridengine

I submit a job to SGE using the `qsub` command and get the error:

```
qsub: Unknown option
```

What unknown option?

Comment: perhaps giving the submission file would help diagnose the problem?

Comment: @BruceBecker, I answered this myself. The answer shows the offending line in the submission file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `qsub` command line options within the script on lines beginning with `#$`. For example:

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
```

If `#$` is not followed by a valid `qsub` option:

```
#$ -invalid_qsub_option
```

You get the unhelpful message:

```
qsub: Unknown option
```

If you get this message, search the script you are submitting for `#$` and make sure it is followed by a valid `qsub` command line option.

If you are really must keep your lines beginning with `#$`, you can specify a different prefix string using the `qsub -C` command line option.